# Send the new inserted value on InfluxDB through HTTP

Tags: kapacitor

I'm trying to figure out how I can raise a notification when a new value is inserted on my influxDB and send a notification to an HTTP endpoint with the data of the new inserted measurement sample. I'm not sure if it's the goal of Kapacitor (I'm new on the TICK stack) or it's better to use another tool (any suggestion will be welcome).

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Albert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Kapacitor` there is two types of task namely `batch` and `stream`. The former is meant for processing historical data and `stream` is for real time purpose.

Looking at your requirement I guess it is obvious that `stream` is the way to go as it will enable you to `watch` data from an influxdb's measurement in real time. For invoking an endpoint in TICK script you can use the `HttpPostNode` node.

**Example (Pseudo code ONLY):**

```
var data = stream
    |from()
        .database('myInfluxDB')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('measurement_ABCD')
    |window()
        .period(10s)
        .every(10s)


data
    |httpPost('http://your.service.url/api/endpoint_xyz')
```

In this instance the TICK script will `watch` for new inserted data on measurement, `measurement_ABCD` for a `window` period of 10 seconds before doing a `HTTP POST` to the defined endpoint and this entire process will repeat again `every` 10 seconds.

That is, you have a moving window of 10 seconds.

Reference:

https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.3/nodes/http_post_node/

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I was thinking more about a messaging pattern where the messages payload are the data just inserted on influxdb. Anyways, I think that the window approach is enough. I'll loop over the new elements at my endpoint.

Comment: Kapacitor is pretty new so it has plenty of limitation lol so yep much easier to do it on the server side if it is easier for you. Will appreciate if you can mark this question as answered by clicking on the Tick beside the helpful solution. Thanks